# Implementing copy assignment operator for Point class

Tags: c++

Consider a point class, with declarations like:

```
// Point.h
class Point {
    public:
        Point();                           // Default constructor
        Point(const Point & p);            // Copy constructor
        Point & operator=(Point source);   // Copy assignment operator, needs implemented
        ~Point();                          // Destructor
    // ...
    private:
        double m_x;                        // X coordinate
        double m_y;                        // Y coordinate
};
```

For the homework, the only thing I have left to implement is the copy assignment operator.
The canonical answer for how to do this is the [copy-and-swap idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom).

Using the swap function for copy assignment solves one problem and creates another (how to implement the swap function).

While I don't feel a need to provide a swap function, I wouldn't know how best to implement swap anyway. Is it to specialize [`std::swap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap)? I know about neither namespaces nor template specialization yet.

Formally, my question is two-fold:

1. How should copy assignment be implemented? If it uses a swap function, how should I implement that?
2. In the wild, would I simply not write the [Big Three members](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29), as the `Point` class is simply two numbers? Will the compiler write the operations correctly and optimally?

Comment: Is the compiler-generated operator not sufficient here? You have no resources that your class is managing.

Comment: The compiler generated version should be sufficient here. But the homework asked for implementations of all three, for practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Copy-and-swap is best practice. If you don't want to override `std::swap` because you're unfamiliar with templates, then you can also write a `swap_points` function or a `Point::swap(Point &other)` member function.

   The implementation of that (member) function is very simple: just call `std::swap` on all of the members.
2. Yes, implementing the Big Three yourself for this class is really an academic exercise.

Answer (score 2):

The naive works here, because `Point` doesn't manage any resources.
Simply copying the double values won't throw an exception, so this code is exception-safe (and in turn is self-assignment safe).

```
// Point.cpp

Point & operator=(Point source);
    m_x = source.m_x;
    m_y = source.m_y;

    return *this;
}
```

Comment: True, but this leads to duplicate code once you decide you do want `std::swap` overloaded on your class.

Comment: Definitely agreed, I just wanted to check if my reasoning was correct.